# How to render a view in php and twig?

Tags: php, twig

I'm creating a webpage where students and teachers log in, teachers create levels and students can do that level.

I explain, I am using php with twig and I want to render a view passing parameters in a function. I've created a budle called Professors where I have the directory Controllers, Models and Templates.

In templates I have professors.html, where I show some information and a button to create a level for students, and also I have crearNivell.html, where the teacher will be able to create the level. When I'm in the page views professors my URL is this one:

[image: localhost/PROJECTE2/professor]

When I click the button "CREATE LEVEL" I want my URL to be like this:

[image: localhost/PROJECTE2/professor/crearNivell]

Instead I get this URL, and this one returns me an error.

[image]

In `Controllers/ProfessorsController.php` I have that code:

```
class ProfessorController extends Controller{

public function process($params)
{
    /*var_dump($params);
    die();*/

    if(empty($params[0])){

        $this->getProfessor(); //Here I return the view professor

    }elseif(isset($params[0]) && $params[0] == "crearNivell"){

        $this->twig = "crearNivell.html";
    }

}

public function getProfessor(){

    $this->twig = "professor.html";
}

}
```

Can someone help me with my code?

When I use `var_dump()` I get this:

[image]

and it should be like that:

[image]

Comment: As fas as I remember, you have to render a template in twig, passing some variables. Check this https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/api.html#rendering-templates

Comment: @icydemon Thanks!! I will check it, but I have to say have to say that I'm not using symfony, i'm using twig implemented in php and I don't know if it works the same

Comment: Twig is not Symfony. Twig is a template engine build by the creators of symfony. Read the documentation, it will enlighten you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to the questions a few days ago. I was complicating myself, it's just like this:

First you create the views, in Templates folder.

The $params are refered to the URL. For example:

**alumne is the bundle**

[image]

**AlumneController.php**

Then in AlumneController.php put the name of the views without the .html and you show it using `$this->twig = "name_Of_The_View.html";`

```
<?php
 class AlumneController extends Controller{

    public function process($params)
    {
        /*var_dump($params);
        die();*/

        if(empty($params[0])){

            $this->getAlumne();
            /*echo $usuari = $_SESSION["username"];*/

        }else if(isset($params[0]) && $params[0] == "instruccions"){

            $this->twig = "instruccions.html";
            /*echo $usuari = $_SESSION["username"];*/

        }else if(isset($params[0]) && $params[0] == "resultats"){

            $this->twig = "resultats.html";
            /*echo $usuari = $_SESSION["username"];*/

        }
    }

    public function getAlumne(){

        $this->twig = "alumne.html";
    }
 }
```

**alumne.html**

And in the button or link you are using to go to the page you write the path in `<a href="bundle/view_name">Instruccions</a>`

```
<a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="alumne/instruccions">Instruccions</a>
<a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="alumne/resultats">Resultats</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the [API of Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/api.html).

More specifically, you need the line below to render a template passing some parameters in array:

```
echo $template->render(['the' => 'variables', 'go' => 'here']);
```

If you use PHP the fastest way to "print" some content to the browser is `echo`, so don't hesitate to use it.

Comment: What does this mean `don't dude`?

Comment: Thanks Ayoze, when I go to class I'll try it!!

Comment: @DarkBee, he wanted to say "do not hesitate to use it"

Comment: Anyway if it's for educational purposes consider use Symfony as @icydemon suggested, you will be giving to your students a real-world knowledge about programming or a framework used in the industry

Comment: Gotcha :) You should add the `load` statement in there as well or go with `echo $twig->render('template.twig', $args);`